# Integration of $\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can anyone show how to calculate $$\int\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du?$$ I can't calculate it.

Comment: Calculate would be a better word. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Stewart tells us to do a trig sub but $\sec^3\theta$ leaves a bit of work...Kaster's approach is much more efficient for whoever actually tries to carry out the computation til the end.

Comment: I don't normally think of this integral as anything special, but having glanced at the responses below I'm filing this one away as a future teaching tool, since it so wonderfully demonstrates the versatility of integration tactics.

Answer (score 10):

Setting
$$
u=\sinh x:=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2},
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du&=&\int\cosh x\sqrt{1+\sinh^2x}\,dx=\int\cosh^2x\,dx=\frac12\int(1+\cosh2x)\,dx\\
&=&\frac{x}{2}+\frac14\sinh2x+C=\frac{x}{2}+\frac12\sinh x\cosh x+C\\
&=&\frac12\ln(u+\sqrt{1+u^2})+\frac12u\sqrt{1+u^2}+C.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: While the tan substitution is the most obious one, I really like this one too. Because it is more (or should I say different) work. Versatility counts too. So upvote!

Answer (score 6):

Let $u = \sinh x$, then
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{1+u^2}du &= \int \cosh x \cdot \cosh x dx = \int \cosh^2x dx = \int \frac {1+\cosh 2x}2 dx = \\
&= \frac x2 + \frac {\sinh 2x}4 + C = \frac {\text{arcsinh } u}2 + \frac {u \sqrt{1+u^2}}2 + C
\end{align}

### PS

To verify: [WA](http://bit.ly/18zfQJK)

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int \sqrt{1+u^2}du = \int \sqrt{1+u^2}\cdot 1\;du$

Using Integration by parts

$\displaystyle I = \sqrt{1+u^2}\cdot u-\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\cdot udu = \sqrt{1+u^2}\cdot u-\int\frac{(1+u^2)-1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}du$

$\displaystyle I = \sqrt{1+u^2}\cdot u-I+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}du$

$\displaystyle 2I = \sqrt{1+u^2}\cdot u+J$

where $\displaystyle J = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}du$

for Calculation of $J$

Let $1+u^2 = v^2$ and $\displaystyle udu = vdv\Rightarrow \frac{du}{v} = \frac{dv}{u} = \frac{d(u+v)}{(u+v)}$

(above Using ratio and Proportion )

So $\displaystyle J = \int\frac{du}{v} = \int\frac{d(u+v)}{(u+v)} = \ln \left|u+v\right|+C$

So $\displaystyle J = \ln \left|u+\sqrt{1+u^2}\right|+C$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{u}{2}\sqrt{1+u^2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|u+\sqrt{1+u^2}\right|+D$

Answer (score 4):

To integrate this we would use Trigonometric substitution. Recall your substitution rules for this. In this case, we would let $u = 1\tan(\theta)$ and then continue to find $d\theta$ so we may do the full substitution.

Comment: It'd be worth noting how you can figure out these substitution relationships by using the $sin^2 + cos^2 = 1$ identity. Then you don't have to memorize anything ;)

Comment: I really would like to see how you'll proceed after that!

Comment: @Mercy It's kinda like your hyperbolic substitution, but ends up with the integral of $\sec^3x$.  If you've either a) memorized the integral of $\sec^3x$, or b) become used to computing integrals like that, so it doesn't phase you, then you're all set. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Let $ u = \tan \theta $. Then, $ \mathrm{d}u = \sec^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta $. Also, note that $$ \sqrt {1 + u^2} = \sqrt {1 + \tan^2 \theta} = \sec \theta. $$Use this to finish.

Comment: I really would like to see how you'll proceed after that!

Comment: @Mercy I simply did not show my work because the OP hasn't shown any him/herself. But it becomes simple Integration by Parts after that.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Mercy Yes. I have tried it.