# About the value of the integral $\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I have two questions about the value of this integral

$$
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt
$$

**First question:** I would like to know if my computations below are correct.

**Second question:** I would like to know if there is a more simple closed form for it value than what I found.

---

Let $t=\sinh x$, then

$$
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi}\cosh^2 x\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi}\mathrm dx+\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi}\sinh^2x\,\mathrm dx\\=\operatorname{arsinh}\pi+\sinh x\cosh x\big|_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi}-\int_0^{\operatorname{arsinh}\pi}\cosh^2 x\,\mathrm dx
$$

Thus I found that

$$
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac12(\operatorname{arsinh}\pi+\pi\cosh\left(\operatorname{arsinh}\pi\right))
$$

and because $\cosh x=\sqrt{\sinh^2 x+1}$ and $\operatorname{arsinh}x=\ln\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$ (for $x\in\Bbb R$ at least) then finally I get the expression

$$
\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac12(\ln(\pi+\sqrt{1+\pi^2})+\pi\sqrt{1+\pi^2})
$$

Comment: For your second question, no.

Comment: $1.$ Your computations are correct. $2.$ Why don't you use the direct formula for $\int {\sqrt{1+x^2}.dx}= \frac{x \sqrt{1+x^2}+ln|x+\sqrt{1+x^2}|}{2}+c$?

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra I dont knew this "direct formula", where you see it?

Comment: Well I didn't see it anywhere, I derived it using integration by part. (Also I am not the only one or first one to derive this XD)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590407/363566 see this answer.